# Mongodb Query for finding distance between latitude and longitude points

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geolocation, geocoding, mongodb-query

I have a **user**'s collection with **Latitude** and **longitude** points for each user.

> I want to calculate distance between given Lat, long values and
>   user's location.

In MYSQL there is a query for it

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Is there any equivalent approach/ Query in **mongodb**? There are ways to accomplish this in Javascript but it would be better if coded in a Query.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongo does not provide you with easy field manipulations like you had in sql world. Some of the [geospatial results give you back the distance](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/) as well, but for the task you want, I would rather do this calculation afterwards. There is a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27928/1090562) which targets you perfectly and among many answers I gave an [optimized javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21623206/1090562) solution.

Comment: Thanks for the links. The issue is i saved Long and lat values in two different fields. Later I realized and updated to [long,lat]. This worked and the JavaScript function is so simple and easy to understand. Thank you.